# Anchor Text box position word

Tags: microsoft-word

I am adding and removing text from textboxes in word, and using "resize shape to fit text", and the box gets smaller at the bottom but I want the box to stay at the bottom of the page and get smaller at the top

Comment: I know of no way to do this. It may be my ignorance speaking, I know. Perhaps you could do this in Publisher. I believe that in Word its position point is the top-left corner of the textbox.

Comment: Using the text box's right-click menu, More layout options..., then setting the Vertical alignment to "Bottom", relative to "Margin" seems to do what you describe but I'm not sure I have understood the requirement.

Comment: @jonsson I think thats worked thanx

Comment: Hope so. Why not give it some time to check it out, then post your own answer if it actually does what you needed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the text box's right-click menu, "More layout options", then setting the Vertical alignment to "Bottom", relative to "Margin".

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).